# Extend XSD with custom attributes?

Tags: xml, xsd

Is there a way to extend XSD elements with custom attributes?

For example, I'd like to do the following in an XSD:

```
<xs:element name="myElement" type="xs:string" myCustomAttribute="true" />
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Extending XSD with custom attributes can be accomplished by first defining the custom attributes in your own namespace, as follows:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xs:schema xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" 
           targetNamespace="http://www.mycompany.com" 
           elementFormDefault="qualified" attributeFormDefault="unqualified">
    <xs:attribute name="myAttribute" type="xs:boolean" default="true"/>
</xs:schema>
```

In this namespace, `http://www.mycompany.com`, a single attribute named `myAttribute` is defined, with a type of `xs:boolean`.

Next, use this namespace in your target schema, as follows:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xs:schema xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" 
           xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" 
           xmlns:mc="http://www.mycompany.com" 
           xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.mycompany.com ./doc.xsd" 
           elementFormDefault="qualified" attributeFormDefault="unqualified">
    <xs:element name="element1" mc:myAttribute="false"/>
</xs:schema>
```

In this example, the `<schema>` element includes attributes that define the custom namespace (`xmlns:mc="http://www.mycompany.com"`), and the location for the custom schema file (`xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.mycompany.com ./doc.xsd"`).

The target schema contains a single element, `"element1"`, and has the custom attribute `myAttribute` defined above, with a value of `"false"`. Note that the name of the custom attribute is prefixed with the custom namespace prefix. Also note that if a value of an invalid type is used (example: `mc:myAttribute="invalid"`), a validation error will be generated.

Credit to @GhislainFourny and @kjhughes for help with this answer.

Answer (score 2):

**No, you cannot add your own components to an XSD without confusing XSD processors.**

For example, Xerces-J, upon encountering your custom attribute example,

```
<xs:element name="myElement" type="xs:string" myCustomAttribute="true" />
```

will respond with the following **error**:

> [Error] try.xsd:3:59: s4s-att-not-allowed: Attribute
>   'myCustomAttribute' cannot appear in element 'element'.

If you want to augment an XSD, use [**`xsd:annotation/xsd:appinfo`**](https://www.w3.org/TR/xmlschema-1/#Annotation_details) or attributes from your own namespace [Credit: [@SpatialBridge]](http://SpatialBridge):

```
<xs:schema xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"
           xmlns:myns="http://www.mycompany.com">
  <xs:element name="myElement" myns:myCustomAttribute="true"/>
</xs:schema>
```

Comment: XMLSpy also produces an error. 

However, qualifying the attribute with a namespace appears to work:

`<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xs:schema xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:myns="http://www.mycompany.com" elementFormDefault="qualified" attributeFormDefault="unqualified">
 <xs:element name="myElement" myns:myCustomAttribute="true">
 </xs:element>
</xs:schema>`

Comment: Yep, that'll work too.  Good idea.  Answer updated.

Comment: Why is that valid, though? I haven't been able to find documentation that answers that. 

It doesn't appear as though the custom attribute actually needs to be defined in the custom namespace. If I `import` my own namespace, no error is raised if the attribute isn't defined, or has `type="xs:integer"`, for example.

Comment: It's valid because the "Schema for Schemas" explicitly states that you can add attributes in your own namespaces: top level elements and local elements allow extra attributes like so: <xs:anyAttribute namespace="##other" processContents="lax"/>. Also, the body of the specification states "any attributes with non-schema namespace" right here: https://www.w3.org/TR/xmlschema-1/#declare-element

Comment: Thanks @GhislainFourny. I still don't understand, however, why I'm not getting validation error on `myns:myCustimAttribute="true"` when I've defined `<xs:attribute name="myCustomAttribute" type="xs:integer" />` in my custom namespace.

Comment: You're welcome! There is a typo in the attribute name (i instead of o), so that it doesn't get validated (lax behavior). You need to validate your schema as a regular XML file (not as an XML schema file) against the schema of schemas + your custom namespace schema, both mentioned in xsi:schemaLocation. processContents=lax should trigger a validation if an attribute declaration is in scope. On my side I get an error as expected "The value 'true' of attribute 'myns:myCustomAttribute' on element 'xs:element' is not valid with respect to its type, 'integer'" I hope this helps!

Comment: @GhislainFournyThanks -- that was a typo in my comment, but it was correct in the file.
I believe that the problem that I was having was that I was not declaring the xsi namespace, and I was specifying schemaLocation in an import tag, rather than in the schema tag. The following schema tag allows for validation:
`<xs:schema xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:mc="http://www.mycompany.com" xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.mycompany.com ./doc.xsd" elementFormDefault="qualified" attributeFormDefault="unqualified">`

Answer (score 0):

XBRL is an example of technology that extends XML Schema with its own custom attributes.

The following example is taken directly from the [XBRL 2.1 specification](http://www.xbrl.org/Specification/XBRL-2.1/REC-2003-12-31/XBRL-2.1-REC-2003-12-31+corrected-errata-2013-02-20.html#_5.1.1.1). xbrli:balance and xbrli:periodType are added by XBRL on top of XML Schema.

```
<element
  id="a2"
  name="fixedAssets"
  xbrli:balance="debit"
  xbrli:periodType="instant"
  type="xbrli:monetaryItemType"
  substitutionGroup="xbrli:item"/>
```

As stated in kjhughes's answer though, you need to use your own namespace (in this case the xbrli prefix is bound with http://www.xbrl.org/2003/instance).