# Generating c# classes from xsd with attributes

Tags: c#, xsd

I need to give support for an old project and i dont have much experince with xsd .
Project run xsd.exe on DataSet.xsd file and generate DataSet.cs file which include genarated c# classes.

I need a flag or attribute on properties of genarated classes .I add a new attribute to xsd file with name **"intradaySupport"** .And i try both as attribute and annotation as in figure below but generated class in DataSet.cs have noting with **"intradaySupport"**.

How should i update my  DataSet.xsd file so final genarated classes have marked with a flag or attribute.

[image]

[image]

**Full of content atached on link just put content to files stated and run xsd**

CDBDataSet.xsd
https://pastebin.com/e0DPAxgb
CustomFields.xsd
[https://pastebin.com/ScS3whrY](https://pastebin.com/e0DPAxgb)

```
enter code here
```

Comment: Can you provide the full xsd document (in text, not an image) so that we can reuse it to reproduce your case?

Comment: @asidis Orginal files are too long , shortened versions are now on links.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to create an attribute in your xsd you have to specify a `<xs:attribute name="intradaySupport" type="xs:boolean" use="required"/>` in your xsd. It should be located just after the xs:sequence:

```
            <xs:element name="AccountType">
                <xs:complexType>
                    <xs:sequence>                          
                        <xs:element name="Account_x0020_type" type="string12" minOccurs="0"  />
                        <xs:element name="Description" type="string40" minOccurs="0" >
                        ...
                        <xs:element name="Not_x0020_used" type="string1" minOccurs="0" />
                    </xs:sequence>
                    <xs:attribute name="intradaySupport" type="xs:boolean" use="required"/>
                </xs:complexType>
            </xs:element>
            ...
```

using xsd.exe /dataset it will generate a boolean column columnintradaySupport in your data set:

```
[global::System.Serializable()]
[global::System.Xml.Serialization.XmlSchemaProviderAttribute("GetTypedTableSchema")]
public partial class AccountTypeDataTable : global::System.Data.DataTable, global::System.Collections.IEnumerable {

    private global::System.Data.DataColumn columnintradaySupport;

    private global::System.Data.DataColumn columnAccount_type;
    ...
}
```

Comment: It cause eror below so i move attribute declaration to another namespace file as stated  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36289219/extend-xsd-with-custom-attributes   "Unable to convert input xml file content to a DataSet. The 'http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema:attribute' element is not supported in this context."

Comment: I updated my answer and I tested it. It works here on my side. Is it what you want ?

Comment: No , ı need meta data on each element tag for example [IntradaySupport("true")]                                                                                private global::System.Data.DataColumn columnAccount_type;

Comment: I think what you are trying to do is not feasible with XSD.exe.
Is it an option to use a partial class and define your attribute in another file aside your generated one?
IMHO, XSD should not contains such metadata