# How to add custom Attributes to ComplexType Elements in xsd?

Tags: c#, xml, xsd

I am generating a c# class file from an XSD provided to me.  I am able to do this without problems if using just the original native XSD.  However, I would like to make modifications to the XSD by adding my own namespace and I would like to feed the newly modified XSD through the generator to produce a class file that contains class definitions I was provided, as well as definitions I have added.

So my understanding is that I need to add a namespace as well as the new attribute under that namespace.  I do have access and the ability to modify the original XSD or add my own xsd.

I looked at this post which was similar [Extend XSD with custom attributes?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36289219/extend-xsd-with-custom-attributes)

An example of my attempt is below.  In my attempt I am trying to add an attribute "Humidity" to the DeviceInfo element under the namespace of "mns".  This currently shows an error of the "'mns:attribute' element is not supported in this context."

test.xsd

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xs:schema xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"
       targetNamespace="http://MyNamespace.com"
       elementFormDefault="qualified" attributeFormDefault="unqualified">
    <xs:element name="DeviceInfo">
        <xs:complexType>
            <xs:attribute name="Humidity" type="xs:float" />
        </xs:complexType>
    </xs:element>
</xs:schema>
```

main.xsd

```
<xs:schema targetNamespace="http://www.CIP4.org/JDFSchema_2_0"
       xmlns="http://www.CIP4.org/JDFSchema_2_0"
       xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"
       xmlns:xsi ="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
       xmlns:mns="http://MyNamespace.com"
       xsi:schemaLocation="http://MyNamespace.com ./test.xsd"
       elementFormDefault="qualified"
       attributeFormDefault="unqualified">
<xs:element name="DeviceInfo">
    <xs:complexType>
        <xs:sequence>
            <xs:element maxOccurs="unbounded" minOccurs="0" ref="Activity"/>
            <xs:element maxOccurs="2" minOccurs="0" ref="FileSpec"/>
            <xs:element maxOccurs="unbounded" minOccurs="0" ref="JobPhase"/>
        </xs:sequence>
        <xs:attribute name="CounterUnit" type="NMTOKEN" use="optional"/>
        <mns:Humidity value="0"/>
</xs:schema>
```

Currently this returns the 'mns:humidity' element is not supported in this context.

Can anybody explain how I can insert this to the complex type?

I also tried placing the mns:Humidity in the same tag as deviceInfo

```
<xs:element name="DeviceInfo mns:Humidity="0">
```

Sending that through the class generator produced two separate instances of "DeviceInfo" where the second had appended a 1.

How can I insert it in the complexType with the namespace?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In main.xsd, in the declaration of DeviceInfo, add

```
<xs:attribute ref="mns:Humidity"/>
```

plus a namespace declaration for "mns" and an `xs:import` declaration for that namespace with `schemaLocation="test.xsd"`.

In `test.xsd` include the single declaration

```
<xs:attribute name="Humidity" type="xs:float"/>
```

Your attempt to solve this suggests that you are using trial and error rather than actually reading up what constructs in XSD actually mean. That isn't a good way forward. You seem fairly confused about the concepts, for example a schema should never contain an `xsi:schemaLocation` attribute.

Comment: Thank you for the reply.  I am currently reading up more on XSD.  I had glazed over some tutorials a little bit in hopes of finding what I needed to know but clearly I clearly did not get enough of an understanding.I am currently reading on w3schools but do you know of any other good references to learn more about XSDs?

Comment: Priscilla Walmsley and Eric van der Vlist have both written good books on XML Schema. It's worth having both, but if I had to choose one, I would probably choose Walmsley.